# Skipping larger chunks while running "Npm run build"

Tags: vue.js, npm, vite

Facing this problem while trying to run "`npm run build`"

```
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 KiB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

Comment: So did you try any of those three things? Without a [mre] there's not much else to say.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you don't want to increase the `chunkSizeWarningLimit` and focus more on solving the actual size issue, Try this solution:

```
export default defineConfig({
....
build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output:{
                manualChunks(id) {
                    if (id.includes('node_modules')) {
                        return id.toString().split('node_modules/')[1].split('/')[0].toString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what this does?

Comment: node_modules is mostly the main reason for the large chunk problem, With this you're telling Vite to treat the used modules separately. To understand better what it does, try to compare the logs from the build command with and without this change.

Answer (score 15):

**EDIT: This is a work around and only hides warnings**

Add  command in vite.config.js

```
build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
  },
```

full code

```
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/Stakepool-Frontend/",
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
  },
});
```

Comment: so this only increases the size limit and does not actually address the size issue?

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer as it only increases the size limit warning.

Comment: This is a work around you are not actually solve the issue

Comment: @JJP which answer works best for you. MohKoma's answer?

Answer (score 6):

While these solutions may seem valid I am not really satisfied with the details provided:

The answer given by Haseeb essentially hides the warning and may lead to more confusion.

MohKomas answer is on the right track but doesn't explain the whys.

I was facing the same issue while working on a Svelte project which relies heavily on the Apache ECharts library (which is quite big when importing it as a whole package). The key was to just import the parts needed and make use of the tree-shakeable interface of the library. Doing this shaved off over 500KiB from the built application.

Answer (score 2):

This is solution for Nuxt3

file: nuxt.confin.ts

```js
export default {
  ...
  vite: {
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          manualChunks(id: any) {
            if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
              return id.toString().split("node_modules/")[1].split("/")[0].toString();
            }
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

it`s work nice

Answer (score -4):

The following worked for me on Vite:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
‌ 
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 100000000
    },
})
```

Comment: The warning is there for a reason. Setting it to some ridiculous high value defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: If you don't care about the warning, you can use this solution, but not recommended. Better to just have the warning if you're not going to address it.